# Abstract class and url mapping

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller, request-mapping

I have an abstract class

I try to have all generic method in this class.

I get issue about mapping.

```
public abstract class BaseControllerNew<T extends BaseEntity, R extends BaseDto, S extends BaseSearch> {
    ...
    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public R getById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id){
        return baseServiceNew.getById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public Page<R> get(Pageable page){
        return baseServiceNew.get(page);
    }
    ....
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/vehicules")
@RestController
public class VehiculesRestController extends BaseControllerNew<Vehicules, VehiculesDto, VehiculesSearch>{

    private VehiculesServiceImpl vehiculesService;

    @Autowired
    public VehiculesRestController(final VehiculesServiceImpl vehiculesService) {
        super(vehiculesService);
        this.vehiculesService = vehiculesService;
    }
```

I'm able to call

/rest/vehicules/1

but i get 404 for

/rest/vehicules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your additional "/", this means your URL will be "/rest/vehicules/"

You only need @GetMapping

```
 @GetMapping
public Page<R> get(Pageable page){
    return baseServiceNew.get(page);
}
```